# UITableView redrawing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

Okay, I'm now stuck for about 3 hours and read all the other threads here and what I could find on Google and did a lot of trialAndError, but it didn't help. Note that I'm a beginner with Objective C and Cocoa Touch.

I got a UITableViewConroller subclass. I want to be able to add cells programmatically. I override the following methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    SectionInfo *obj = nil;
    obj = [dataSourceMutableArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return [obj GetNumberOfCells];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [dataSourceMutableArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    CellInfo *cellInfo = nil;
    SectionInfo *si = [dataSourceMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cellInfo = [si.cellInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cellInfo.mypath = indexPath;
    cell = cellInfo.cell;

    return cell;
}
```

The CellInfo and SectionInfo objects are just wrappers. A sectionInfo contains an array of CellInfo object, which again contains the cell. The view gets drawn as expected, no matter which sections and cells I initialize.

When I later on add a cell to a section, and call [tableViewController.tableView reloadData];, nothing happens. Setting a breakpoint in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" and "numberOfRowsInSection" shows me that "cellForRowAtIndexPath" gets called when I drag the table view out of sight, but "numberOfRowsInSection" never gets called again. Might this be the problem?

I also tried stuff like this:

```
NSArray* a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:                      [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0],                        [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0],                         [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1],                        [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:1],                       nil];

[tableViewController.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:a withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Also didn't trigger any breakpoints. If you need more info please let me know. I hope I'm just blind and you can spot the mistake.

Comment: Or is there another way of setting the datasource on the tableView that overriding those methods and return the values it needs?

Comment: Hm, I just found the tableView.dataSource member... class 'NSMutableArray' does not implement the 'UITableViewDataSource' protocol... is implementing this protocol a possiblity to get the view updating when I change the datasource by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, sorry, but my question did not cover the mistake I made. The problem was, that I was missing to set a reference to my controller class. I ran into this problem now sometimes, coming from languages that give you NullPointerExceptions. So my only advice for everyone if something doesn't work is to check everythings initialized correctly. Sorry for causing work for anyone looking at this question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe by doing:

```
[tableViewController.tableView beginUpdates];
[tableViewController.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:a withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableViewController.tableView endUpdates];
```

From Apple doc:

> after endUpdates returns—the table
>   view queries its data source and
>   delegate as usual for row and section
>   data

I usually do it by simply using the reloadData when I have a new row/section to display (making sure numberOfRow & numberOfSection return the proper number of items).

Hope this helps.